# Is there a way to detect there is no battery on the device in js?

Tags: javascript, battery, minix

I have a minix ks controller which is working from plug and doesn't have a battery.
However I'm getting battery data from JS navigator object:

[image]

This is what I'm getting from getBattery method:

[image]

But I need to detect there is no battery in the device to not show battery indicator on the screen. Is there any way in JS to detect there is no battery at all?

Comment: That's not the format of what `getBattery` returns. How are you getting the battery status?

Comment: updated the post with object I'm getting in navigator

Comment: @Olga That seems to be wrong, which browser are you using? `navigator.getBattery` returns a promise and also navigator does not have a battery property anymore (Chrome  v99.0.4844.84). The battery propety was deprecated. `getBattery` gives you access to `[charging]: boolean`, `[chargingTime]: number`, `[dischargingTime]: number` and `[level]: number`.

Comment: I added one more picture on the object returned by getBattery()

Comment: @Olga Ah ok, it seems like you are using an older version of a browser. You could make a guess based on the chargingTime property which defaults to 0 if the device cannot provide the information. But I am not sure if that is a 100% accurate way of doing it as there might be a different reason for why the charging time was not provided by the device e.g. missing permission. https://www.w3.org/TR/battery-status/#the-batterymanager-interface

Comment: Reading the BatteryManager MDN docs, they say if there is no battery the `level` defaults to 1.